# How set cell name for formula in HSSFDataValidation

Tags: excel, validation, apache-poi, hssf, hssfworkbook

i want cell value between two cells value.
I use HSSFDataValidation for set validation to excel file that create by apache poi but error when execute.

> source code:

```
HSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new HSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
DVConstraint dvConstraint =(DVConstraint) dvHelper.createNumericConstraint
             (DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.DECIMAL,
              DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.BETWEEN,
              "G3", 
              "H3");
CellRangeAddressList  addressList=new CellRangeAddressList (2,rowNum,8,8);
DataValidation validation =dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

> error :

```
The supplied text 'G3' could not be parsed as a number
```

Comment: [Data Validations](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Data+Validations): "The values passed to the two String parameters can be formulas; the '=' symbol is used to denote a formula." So `"=G3"` and `"=H3"`.

Comment: @Axel Richter:  When use this format run without error but not working correctly

Comment: Not clear what "not working correctly" means. Maybe you mean the number must be between `"=$G$3"` and `"=$H$3"`? Note the `$` which makes the cell references absolute while `"=G3"` and `"=H3"` are relative and will change in each different cell the validation is applied to.

Comment: when using `"=G3"` and `"=H3"` in Excel file set validation between `O5` and `P5`. but when using `"=$G$3"` and `"=$H$3"` working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this format for formula:  `"=$G$3"` and `"=$H$3"`